# How do I Change culture to allow (i.e.) spanish datetime in MVC POST?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, datetime, datepicker

I checked 10 thousand posts already, none of them did the trick about this very simple problem.

On my UI I have a `TextBoxFor` for a DateTime property (on my model) very standard stuff.

**Model**

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
public DateTime DateTo { get; set; }
```

**View**

```
        <div class="Label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DateTo)
        </div>
        <div class="Control">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DateTo, "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", new { @class = "datepicker" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DateTo)
        </div>
```

**jQuery / DatePicker**

Just in case, this is the code behind datepicker, I think it's pretty standard from jQuery datepicker, note that *In the UI I see datepicker working as expected*.

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy", changeYear: true, showAnim: 'blind' });
```

**Culture**

So what I learned from other posts, you could change culture to achieve this, but didn't work, I overrided `OnActionExecuting` with this code:

```
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("ES-AR");
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("ES-AR");
```

I can see in the Inspection window, that the culture is "es-ar", but problem persists.

**Problems!**

Problem 1:
If I wrote something like '01/02/2018', MVC automatic mapping thinks it's 2nd of January... But actually is meant to be 1st of February.

Problem 2:
If I wrote something like '31/03/2018', MVC automatic mapping thinks it's a wrong date (like month 30) but actually is meant to be 30th of march.

Even page validator says "`The value '31/03/2018' is not valid for DateTo.`"

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oookey, while explaining this, I got the solution (rubber ducked stackoverflow :/ )...

Solution, It works fine if you put this in your config:

```
<globalization culture="es-AR" uiCulture="es-AR" />
```

**The new problem I see**, what if I wan't to change culture realtime to go back to EN-US? (To change thread culture seems to be the solution, but didn't work as I mentioned above)

For now, it solved my problem.